# Make enum bindable to datagridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enums

I have an object which contains a number of string properties and an enum property called CRAction.

I have another object which represents a collection of the above object.

When I bind the collection object to something like a gridview, all of the string properties bind fine, but the enum doesn't appear.

I have added another string property which returns CRAction.ToString, but is there a better way to make an enum bindable to a control as part of an object?

It all seems a little hackish to have another property for the same thing purely for data binding!

Comment: are you trying to expose the integral value or the friendly identifier?  In otherwords, given an enum like this: enum Days {Sat = 1, Sun = 2, Mon = 3, Tue = 4, Wed = 5, Thu= 6, Fri = 7}; would you be trying to display "mon" or "3" on the screen?

Comment: My enum declaration looks like this:

Public Enum CRAction
          Edit
          View
End Enum

I think in my case, the integral value and friendly identifier are one and the same?

 Basically, I think I need a way to automatically tostring the enum value when databound.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<asp:Label> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CRAction") %></asp:Label>
```